# How to assign custom dispatcher in java-akka using parent actor context?

Tags: java, akka

I created an actor system in java using akka, in the following way. Also I created the supervisor actor.

> final ActorSystem system = getSystem();
>           system.actorOf(Props.create(Supervisor.class), Supervisor.NAME);

I updated the default dispatcher in the following way.

```
akka {
      default-dispatcher {
        # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
        type = Dispatcher
        # What kind of ExecutionService to use
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
        # Configuration for the fork join pool
        fork-join-executor {
          # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
          parallelism-min = 256
          # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
          parallelism-factor = 40.0
          # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
          parallelism-max = 512
        }
        # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
        # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
        # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
        throughput = 1
      }
}
```

The problem Im facing is when I write a custom dispatcher for a particular actor. In that it does not recognize the pattern of the actor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the "deployment" section to your config.

Code:

```
ActorRef myActor =
  system.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class),
    "myactor");
```

Config:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /myactor {
    dispatcher = my-dispatcher
  }
}
```

Look at [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/dispatchers.html#setting-the-dispatcher-for-an-actor)